# Call last cell in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I want to change the image of the last cell if the user click on a new cell. For now im doing this:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        //Old Cell Image
        let lastCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: self.lastCell) as! DataTableViewCell!;
        lastCell?.imageButton.image = UIImage(named: "RadioButtomDeactive.png")

        let indexPathCel = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;
        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPathCel!) as! DataTableViewCell!;

        dateSelected = currentCell?.dateSession.text
        currentCell?.imageButton.image = UIImage(named: "RadioButtom.png")

    }
```

I tried to save the `indexPath.row` in `lastCell` (that is an int) but it didn't work since `cellForRow` only accept `indexPath`.

Comment: Just create the NSIndexPath for the last cello and use it to reference the last cell.NSIndexPath(forRow: 2, inSection: 0), just replace the fixed number 2 here with your data source count

Comment: Yeah that was an easy solution, didn't know how could i not see this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply create an `IndexPath` using your stored `lastCell` via:

```
IndexPath(row: self.lastCell, section: 0)
```

If there is more than one section, you'll just need to insert your last section instead of `0`.

Comment: Yeah thats pretty much solves the problem. Thanks dervs!

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you keep in memory the IndexPath instead of an Int ?

or

you can create an IndexPath from your Int with

```
IndexPath(row: Int, section: Int)
```

Comment: Thats it, Anthony! Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I have a very different solution.

```
var selectedIndexPath: IndexPath?

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                        cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    ...
    if indexPath == selectedIndexPath {
        cell.imageButton.image = UIImage(named: "RadioButtom.png")
    } else {
        cell.imageButton.image = UIImage(named: "RadioButtomDeactive.png")
    }
    ...
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath

    if let visibleIndexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows {
        tableView.reloadRows(at: visibleIndexPaths, with: .none)
    }
}
```

Using a variable to hold the currently selected index, I can tell cell for row at index path which cell should get the image, all others get the default. When a row is selected, I note the new index path of the currently selected row then tell all visible cells to reload themselves. That causes cell for row at index path to rebind all the data.

Comment: Thats a very good solution but i don't see why would i reload all rows if i could just save the indexPath of the current cell and use it when the user click on another one.

Comment: @Adrian You are not reloading all the rows, only the visible one. The answer is why not? There will only be a hand-full of visible rows, so no performance hit. In addition, all the logic for how cells look is all kept in cell for row at index path.

Comment: I see. Thats a very elegant solution indeed.